# Converting to same date format using format of Moment JS gives invalid date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a react application where at one place we are converting date using moment like this

```
moment("08/19/1994", 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).isValid()
```

this returns the date as "19/08/1994 and this value is stored in redux store.

When the component is again refreshed, this conversion happens again and this time it works like this

```
moment("19/08/1994", 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).isValid() //invalid date.
```

So if we are converting same date format it is giving the error So is there a way we can check the format or git rid of this invalid date using any other method.

Comment: "08/19/1994" vs "19/08/1994", not same

Comment: @JosephWang I mean second time conversion, 19/08/1994 and format (DD/MM/YYYY) is same so it gives invalid date.

Comment: Full code or online demo would be better for others to catch up with the problem you are facing

Comment: `moment("08/19/1994", 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).isValid()` returns false.

Comment: `moment("19/08/1994", 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).isValid()` returns true.

Comment: Store the `moment`, the `Date` object (from `moment().toDate()`), or or the date in a universal format, like ISO (`toISOString()`) in the redux store.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the date only the first time you store it in redux, not in the react component.

Answer (score 0):

`isValid()` returns boolean based on the date validity

Use `format()` to convert date to `'DD/MM/YYYY'`

```js
console.log(moment("08/19/1994", 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. this works fine first time when we convert but when component will again update the date will be passed as 19/08/1994 after conversion and agin it will cause a issue. I hope I was able to explain

Comment: Again, You should convert the date only the first time you store it in redux, not in the react component.